# Should we use own threads or thread pool for small and frequent tasks?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, threadpool

In my application I have a set of plugins - classes that do some small actions when some events happen in application. Each method of a plugin must be invoked in a separate thread, though only one method of each plugin can be run simultaneously.

I can implement this using two ways:

1. Create single thread for each plugin which will handle events from plugin's queue until queue is empty. Then sleep until new event comes to queue, handle it and so on.
2. When events come to a plugin's queue process it in thread-pool thread. When queue becomes empty release it back to thread pool.

The question is: **What are the advantages and disadvantages of both ways?**

Some clarifications:

- Plugins don't load CPU too much, most of the time they just wait for the next event.
- I don't care about time needed to create a thread, plugins are long-living.
- Usually I have ~10-20 such plugins per application.

Comment: "though only one method of each plugin can be run simultaneously" - Do you mean that for a given plugin, you can't be calling two methods on it simultaneously? But if you had separate plugins, you could execute methods on those different plugins simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

> Each method of a plugin must be invoked in a separate thread, though only one method of each plugin can be run simultaneously.

If this is your requirement, I would consider building the plugins around a `BlockingCollection<T>`.  When you add a plugin, start a long running task that just does a `foreach` on `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`.

This would allow you to add items to their "queue", and the plugin would automatically process those items in order, without requiring your own "sleep" handling.  Each plugin could just use `blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable` to process items in its queue.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it done both ways.  What gets ugly with one thread per plugin is this- you start to rely on the idea that "only one thread ever touches my plugin", and then someone makes a mistake where one plugin's thread goes and touches some other plugin (though convoluted event handling or something similar).  Then you end up with very hard-to-track race conditions.

The approach that @Reed-Copsey suggests is far cleaner, but if you must go with one of the two approaches you mentioned, then using the thread pool and locking appropriately will save you some heartache later on.  This especially applies if you have multiple team members working on multiple aspects of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with #2. The reason being that you aren't keeping around a bunch of threads that are idle most of the time. There's really no disadvantage of doing it this way since you also get parallelism between different plugins and sequential execution for each given plugin.